# Does Convert.ToString(string value) do anything?

Tags: c#

Just curious if there is some reason to use [Convert.ToString(string value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's probably just for consistency.

Comment: Other than if you want to maintain a consistent look across a block of code, no, there's not really a good reason to use the functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does nothing, the original string is returned.

See: [Convert.ToString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the specified string instance; **no actual conversion is
>   performed**.

This is how it is [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1959)

```
public static String ToString(String value) {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == value);  // We were always skipping the null check here.
    return value;
}
```

*Just to add one more thing*, `System.Convert` has methods to covert each type to itself like [Convert.ToInt32 Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a76a1x(v=vs.110).aspx) and in all cases these methods do nothing, the actual value is returned.

Comment: For posting the implementation plus one :)

Comment: However, `Convert.ToString((object)str)` *does* do something different, which has bit me a few times. Not exactly the most uniform behavior.

Comment: @user2864740, yes it will return empty string `""`, something that I use a lot :)